# How to parse literal block with user supplied START and END token

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to parse a language that has a block with user supplied start/end mark, see following example

```
@IDENT1
text... text...
text ...
IDENT1
```

OR

```
@@IDENT2
text... text...
text ...
IDENT2
```

are both valid block, but following is not

```
@IDENT1
text ... text...
IDENT2
```

How could I write a rule in ANTLR4 to parse this?

Comment: Assuming `IDENT1` can be any identifier, not just a hand full of numbered `IDENT...` ids. Then the answer is: not without a semantic predicate, which means adding target specific code to your grammar. What language are you using?

Comment: I am using c++. Yes the IDENT1 can be any identifier.

Comment: OK, but with C++ I can't give  an example.

Comment: I'd consider myself an ANTLR newbie.  if you use a parse tree listener, then you could have a @IDENT entry rule which pushes the value of IDENT somewhere in the CPP code. Then the IDENT exit rule would check the value pushed to make sure it matches.
It's probably not the elegant solution.  If I have time I could code up an answer maybe later this or next week.

Comment: @BartKiers example in any language is fine

Comment: @RossYoungblood hmm, but in order for listener to be trigger, I need to craft a parse rule first,then walk it, right? I could see how that could work, basically parse tree could accept  anything start with @ or @@ , then have a post step to actually validate it is a valid block.

Comment: @叶雨飞 I posted a Java demo

Answer (score 0):

> @BartKiers example in any language is fine

OK, here's a demo for the Java runtime:

```
lexer grammar BlockLexer;

@members {
  private boolean blockEndAhead(String matchedText) {

    if (this._input.LA(1) == EOF) {
      // There apaprently is no proper closing block ahead, because we've stumbled upon the end-of-file token
      return false;
    }

    String startBlock = matchedText.replaceAll("^@+(\\w+)[\\s\\S]+$", "$1");

    for (int ahead = 1; ahead <= startBlock.length(); ahead++) {
      char charAhead = (char)this._input.LA(ahead);

      if (charAhead != startBlock.charAt(ahead - 1)) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
}

BLOCK
 : '@'+ IDENTIFIER [ \t\r\n]+
   // Match as much chars as possible until we "see" the opening ID ahead in the char stream
   ({!this.blockEndAhead(getText())}? . )*
   // Make sure the proper closing ID is ahead, if not, the lexer will fall through to `INVALID_BLOCK`
   {this.blockEndAhead(getText())}? IDENTIFIER
 ;

// Match a dangling open-ID that has no closing ID
INVALID_BLOCK
 : '@'+ IDENTIFIER [ \t\r\n]+ ({!this.blockEndAhead(getText())}? . )*
 ;

// Fall through rule: matches any single char if none of the lexer rules above have matched
UNKNOWN : . ;

fragment IDENTIFIER
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;
```

Given the test input:

```
@IDENT1
text... text...
text ...
IDENT1

noise

@@IDENT2
text... text...
text ...
IDENT2

noise

@IDENT1
text ... text...
IDENT2
```

and if you generate a lexer and run the following Java code:

```java
String source = "@IDENT1\n" +
    "text... text...\n" +
    "text ...\n" +
    "IDENT1\n" +
    "\n" +
    "noise\n" +
    "\n" +
    "@@IDENT2\n" +
    "text... text...\n" +
    "text ...\n" +
    "IDENT2\n" +
    "\n" +
    "noise\n" +
    "\n" +
    "@IDENT1\n" +
    "text ... text...\n" +
    "IDENT2";

BlockLexer lexer = new BlockLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
CommonTokenStream stream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
stream.fill();

for (Token t : stream.getTokens()) {
  System.out.printf("%-35s `%s`%n",
      BlockLexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(t.getType()),
      t.getText().replace("\n", "\\n"));
}
```

the following will be printed:

```
BLOCK                               `@IDENT1\ntext... text...\ntext ...\nIDENT1`
UNKNOWN                             `\n`
UNKNOWN                             `\n`
UNKNOWN                             `n`
UNKNOWN                             `o`
UNKNOWN                             `i`
UNKNOWN                             `s`
UNKNOWN                             `e`
UNKNOWN                             `\n`
UNKNOWN                             `\n`
BLOCK                               `@@IDENT2\ntext... text...\ntext ...\nIDENT2`
UNKNOWN                             `\n`
UNKNOWN                             `\n`
UNKNOWN                             `n`
UNKNOWN                             `o`
UNKNOWN                             `i`
UNKNOWN                             `s`
UNKNOWN                             `e`
UNKNOWN                             `\n`
UNKNOWN                             `\n`
INVALID_BLOCK                       `@IDENT1\ntext ... text...\nIDENT2`
EOF                                 `<EOF>`
```